# google map api can't find location

Tags: c#, google-maps

I wrote a C# program using google map API and found out that for some Lat & 
Long locations, the API can't find the address(when google earth able to 
find it...).
Below is a code that demonstrate it:

```
============================
...
using Google.Api.Maps.Service.Geocoding;
...
var request = new GeocodingRequest();
request.Sensor = "false";
request.Language = "iw";
request.LatitudeLongitude = "33.00166,35.60089";
var response = GeocodingService.GetResponse(request);
```

Then:   *response.Status is: ServiceResponseStatus.Ok*

**But using the same code with the following location:**

```
request.LatitudeLongitude = "33.14640,35.72904";
response.Status became:  ServiceResponseStatus.ZeroResults
```

However, google earth find the address for this location, so why the google 
map API can't find it?

Please advise,
Lots of tnkx,
golan

Answer (score 0):

You have `ServiceResponseStatus.ZeroResults` response, because you try reverse geocoding in the disputed area (33.14640,35.72904).

https://google-developers.appspot.com/maps/documentation/utils/geocoder/#q%3D33.1464%252C35.72904

Unfortunately, Google Maps reverse geocoding doesn't work in disputed areas. This is a known issue and it was reported in Google issue tracker as [issue 35826813](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/35826813). It looks like Google is currently working on this problem, because the status of the issue is Accepted. There is no workaround at the moment for Google Maps API.

I can suggest starring the issue to express your interest and receive further updates from Google.

#### Update

Good news. As of January 2019 Google resolved an issue with ZERO_RESULTS in disputed areas.

You can see that now they return results, but country name doesn't appear in responses. This aligns with approach that they had in forward geocoder. Disputed areas don't have country names.